# Propositional Logic - Distributive Law - Help to Resolve My Conflict of Intuition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm just starting to learn propositional logic, and I'm hung up on the part of the Distributive Law specifically on the distribution of the $\vee$ (or) operator, where if $P \vee (Q \wedge R)$ then $(P \vee Q) \wedge (P \vee R)$. My problem with the statement boils down to the fact that intuitively in the first clause, regardless of the truth value of $P$, the truth values of $Q$ and $R$ have to be the same as one another (both true or both false), right? However, in the second clause, my understanding intuitively is that if $P$ is true, then $Q$ and $R$ can have different truth values (and do not need to be both true or both false). Hence, I do not see how the Distributive Law equivalence holds, and I'm also having trouble finding where I'm going wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You ask: "*in the first clause, regardless of the truth value of P, the truth values of Q and R have to be the same as one another, right?*" Not right. E.g. it could be that $P$ and $Q$ are true, but $R$ is false. Then $Q$ and $R$ have different truth values, $Q \wedge R$ is not true, but $P$ is true, and since one of the disjuncts is true, the whole disjunction $P\vee (Q \wedge R)$ is true.

Comment: Ohhhhh, I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: @Z.A.K. You may want to post your comment as an answer, or @ Paeon, you may want to self-answer your question to remove it from the unanswered section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Z.A.K.,

'You ask: "in the first clause, regardless of the truth value of P, the truth values of Q and R have to be the same as one another, right?" Not right. E.g. it could be that P and Q are true, but R is false. Then Q and R have different truth values, Q∧R is not true, but P is true, and since one of the disjuncts is true, the whole disjunction P∨(Q∧R) is true.'